# Lastlogin not updating on login

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, basically when the user logs in I'm trying to update the "lastlogin" field in the users database.

```
$login = login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
        $sql = "UPDATE `users` (lastlogin) VALUES ('now()') WHERE `user_id` = $user_id";
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `'` on `now()` function, add SET:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET lastlogin = now() WHERE `user_id` = $user_id";
```

You are not executing any mysql functions, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or old/depricated [mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php)

Think about adding:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$res = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET lastlogin = now() WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
```

Comment: shouldnt it be `UPDATE users SET lastlogin=now() WHERE userid=$user_id`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, still not updating :(

Comment: You used `INSERT` syntax, `UPDATE` is slightly different

Comment: Thanks Mirk, I am currently unfamiliar with mysqli coding, so I'll need to do some reading and work out how to try what you posted, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `users` set lastlogin  = now() WHERE `user_id` = $user_id";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not working, I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: echo the query and run the query in phpmyadmin

Comment: "Unknown column '$user_id' in 'where clause'"

Comment: Simply means that you dont have any attribute/column named user_id in your table?

Comment: @user2571547 check that you didn't run WHERE `$user_id`=

Comment: No I ran 

UPDATE `users` set lastlogin  = now() WHERE `user_id` = $user_id

And user_id is in the users table.